# Cant access JProgressbar from button [Java]

Tags: java, error-handling, jprogressbar

With the windowsbuilder i've created a little gui in eclipse.
And in the action event of a button ive written this code:

```
progressBar.setValue(0);
```

but that does not work.
"progressBar cannot be resolved"
Please Help!
ps: i'm new to Java
EDIT:

```
JButton allButton = new JButton("Klick Mich!");
    allButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            progress1.setValue(50);
            main.infoBox("Hallo Welt!", "Hallo Welt!");


        }
    });
```

EDIT2:

```
JProgressBar progress1 = new JProgressBar();
    progress1.setStringPainted(true);
    progress1.setBounds(20, 124, 408, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(progress1);
}
```

EDIT3 [COMPLETE CODE]
http://pastebin.com/68z1Mpen

Comment: did you create a JProgressBar() instance?

Comment: yes, but i've also tried in with other names

Comment: could you show relevant codes

Comment: hm have added a little. its just a simple Hello World program.

Comment: show the code of creating progress1??

Comment: have added. was generated from windows builder.

Comment: it would be better if you showed a bit more code, just the button won't do - the error might be elsewhere. Post your class or multiple classes. You might have a problem with the declaration of the progress bar

Comment: okay have added pastebin with complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have created jprogressbar after you access it.you have to create before access

like this

```
JProgressBar progress1 = new JProgressBar();
JButton allButton = new JButton("Klick Mich!");
allButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        progress1.setValue(50);
        main.infoBox("Hallo Welt!", "Hallo Welt!");    
    }
});
```

when you call

```
progress1.setValue(50);
```

`progress1` isn't declared .so that's why you are getting a error

Comment: Won't you need progress1 to be declared final?

Answer (score 0):

Make a `JProgressBar progress1` a class field to access it from inner class

```
public class main {
    private JProgressBar progress1;
    private JFrame frame;
...
}
```

and declare it by:

```
progress1 = new JProgressBar();
```

or make `JProgressBar progress1` final.